# Why ClassName breaks this code?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created 2 simple elements:

```js
var mydragg = function() {
  return {
    move: function(div, xpos) {
      div.style.left = xpos + 'px';
    },
    startMoving: function(div, container, evt) {
      evt = evt || window.event;
      var posX = evt.clientX,
        divLeft = div.style.left,
        eWi = parseInt(div.style.width = "200px"),
        cWi = parseInt(document.getElementById(container).style.width = "200px");

      document.getElementById(container).style.cursor = 'move';

      divLeft = divLeft.replace('px', '');
      var diffX = posX - divLeft;
      document.onmousemove = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var posX = evt.clientX,
          aX = posX - diffX;
        if (aX < 0) aX = 0;
        if (aX > cWi) aX = cWi;

        mydragg.move(div, aX);
      }
    },
    stopMoving: function(container) {
      var a = document.createElement('script');
      document.getElementById(container).style.cursor = 'default';
      document.onmousemove = function() {}
    },
  }
}();
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="green dragme" onmousedown='mydragg.startMoving(this,"container",event);' onmouseup='mydragg.stopMoving("container");'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper wrapper-red">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="red dragme" onmousedown='mydragg.startMoving(this,"container",event);' onmouseup='mydragg.stopMoving("container");'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine (green and red block are dragging by mouse - https://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/GvMNPW), but there shouldn't be multiple ids with the same name. So I've changed ids ('container') to classes, after that code does not work: https://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/OjxWJO?editors=1010

Comment: Where is your changed/modified code that “does not work”?

Comment: https://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/OjxWJO?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `document.getElementById(container)`, as you said yourself it's a class not an id. You should call `document.getElementsByClassName` instead.

However you're just querying the document for all classnames with this name, so you will get multiple and not know which to select. There are many solutions but one is that it might just be easier to select the parent element with `div.parentElement`:

https://codepen.io/ferahl/pen/oeGBgL

Comment: That’s half the job only ... you also need to access specific elements inside the returned NodeList afterwards ...

Comment: And take care: ´getElementById(container)´ returns one element, ´getElementyByClassName´ returns multiple objects. you may need an [0] after the command

Comment: True, I answered too quickly.. will edit when I look at the code

Comment: I've changed not only HTML, but CSS and JS as well.

Comment: Oswald, thank you! Works fine! Changed to document.getElementsByClassName(container)[0]

Answer (score 0):

You can just send the element to javascript, and in javascript you just access direct to the element you sent , no need to query the element again.

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">     
    <div class="green dragme" onmousedown='mydragg.startMoving(this,event);' 
    onmouseup='mydragg.stopMoving(this);'>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper wrapper-red">
    <div class="container">     
        <div class="red dragme" onmousedown='mydragg.startMoving(this,event);' 
        onmouseup='mydragg.stopMoving(this);'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

> ```
> var mydragg = function(){
> return {
>   move : function(div,xpos){
>     div.style.left = xpos + 'px';
>   },
>   startMoving : function(div,evt){
>     evt = evt || window.event;
>     var posX = evt.clientX,
>         divLeft = div.style.left,
>         eWi = parseInt(div.style.width = "200px"),
>         cWi = parseInt(div.style.width = "200px");
>
>     div.style.cursor='move';
>
>     divLeft = divLeft.replace('px','');
>     var diffX = posX - divLeft;
>     document.onmousemove = function(evt){
>       evt = evt || window.event;
>       var posX = evt.clientX,
>             aX = posX - diffX;
>       if (aX < 0) aX = 0;
>       if (aX > cWi) aX = cWi;
>
>       mydragg.move(div,aX);
>     }
>   },
>   stopMoving : function(container){
>     var a = document.createElement('script');
>     container.style.cursor='default';
>     document.onmousemove = function(){}
>   },
> }   }();
> ```